# How can I automatically open Tex/PDF/Markdown previews side-by-side with the markup when opening the source file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, preview

On my Visual Studio Code, I edit .tex files + PDF preview (Latex Workshop extension) and .md files + Markdown preview. I do that at the same time, and I have a split view where the two source files are on the left and the previews are on the right.

I was wondering whether it's possible to tie together source + preview file, in a way that if I open the source code it will automatically open a preview on the right as well.

Comment: I'm unclear on what "*switch to the right preview*" means. Do you mean when you open the source file, it automatically does the action of "Open Preview" command and opens it on the right side?

Comment: @GinoMempin yes!

Comment: For anyone interested in just opening the preview and not the side-by-side, see [How can I open a Markdown file in preview mode by default in VS Code?](/q/76389311/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Markdown part of the question here is the subject of a feature-request that is still open at the time of this writing: [Automatically Activate Markdown Preview #2766](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2766). Give it a thumbs up to show support, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress, but please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" or "bump". The maintainers are also soliciting further discussion on use-cases. See [this comment there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2766#issuecomment-375829223).

If you're using an extension that provides [a custom editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors) that has the split of text and preview in it, you can use the `workbench.editorAssociations` setting to get what you want.